# How to choose duration of auto-renewable subscription before purchasing

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Auto renewable subscription has one id but can have multiple durations. 
I was wondering how can i specify duration user choose to buy but there is no such field as "duration" in SKProduct.
**Question:** is it correct that it's impossible to choose duration of auto-renewable subscription in code but instead user chooses one in native dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duration you have to infer from product id in iTunes. There is no other alternative. 
As par Apple Documentation

> The length of the subscription is not provided in by the
>   SKPaymentTransaction object or in the receipt data returned by the App
>   Store receipt validator. You should use a different product identifier
>   for each subscription length so that your application can convert a
>   product identifier into a subscription length.

E.g. com.mycompany.6monthssub
     com.mycompany.1yearsub

Comment: I believe you talking about non-renewable subscriptions. Receipt for auto-renewable subscription actually contains duration, proofs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html but it's only something that describes a purchase that was made. I wonder when one specifies duration when he buys auto-renewable subscription.

Comment: No i am talking about auto-renewable subscriptions (check out the last paragarph of http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html)

Comment: So i tested it and it turned out you are right. Each period of time has it's own id in itunesconnect.